# MS ACCESS query

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2003

This query is not working because of two columns in the Where condition (`tblEventLog.PartNumberChgLvl`). 
How should I change the query to work it out?

```
strNewSql1 = _
    "SELECT DISTINCT " & _
        "tblRevRelLog_Detail.PartNumber, " & _
        "tblRevRelLog_Detail.ChangeLevel " & _
    "FROM tblRevRelLog_Detail LEFT JOIN tblEventLog " & _
        "ON (tblEventLog.PartNumber = tblRevRelLog_Detail.PartNumber) " & _
        "AND (tblEventLog.PartNumberChgLvl " & _
            "= tblRevRelLog_Detail.ChangeLevel) " & _
    "WHERE (tblEventLog.PartNumber, tblEventLog.PartNumberChgLvl) NOT IN " & _
        "(SELECT tblEventLog.PartNumber, tblEventLog.PartNumberChgLvl " & _
        "FROM tblEventLog " & _
        "WHERE tblEventLog.EventTypeSelected = 'pn REMOVED From Wrapper' " & _
            "AND tblEventLog.PartNumber =  tblRevRelLog_Detail.PartNumber " & _
            "AND tblEventLog.PartNumberChgLvl " & _
                "= tblRevRelLog_Detail.ChangeLevel) " & _
        "AND tblEventLog.TrackingNumber = """ & tempTrackingNumber & """ " & _
        "AND tblEventLog.PartNumber =  tblRevRelLog_Detail.PartNumber " & _
        "AND tblEventLog.PartNumberChgLvl =  tblRevRelLog_Detail.ChangeLevel;"
```

I am showing this by using an example.

**example: lets take two packages 1 and 2**

package 1 has a-1, b-0, c-1 Partnumber with changelevels and
package 2 has a-1, d-1, e-1 Partnumber with changelevels

if I remove "a-1" from the package 1, that should no show up with that package but it should show up with package 2. With this query it is not showing up in the package 2 also.

Reviewrelease_Form(main form) linked to reviewreleasetable:

this table contains basic data and wrapper number

wrapper number:  RevRel_Form(subform) linked to tblRevRelLog_Detail

**event_Input is the subform where we enter events. When I select an event It will display the partnumbers. This is where the query comes into picture.**

This should not display removed partnumbers. That is working fine. But if the same part number with same changelevl is removed from diff package..it is also not showing up in the current package.

Answer (score 0):

When are you using the "IN" comparison operator, you can only compare one value to a set of values.

So you would need to change that portion of your WHERE clause to:

```
WHERE 
tblEventLog.PartNumber NOT IN(SELECT tblEventLog.PartNumber FROM tblEventLog WHERE tblEventLog.EventTypeSelected = 'pn REMOVED From Wrapper'AND tblEventLog.PartNumber = tblRevRelLog_Detail.PartNumber AND tblEventLog.PartNumberChgLvl = tblRevRelLog_Detail.ChangeLevel) and

tblEventLog.PartNumberChgLvl NOT IN(SELECT tblEventLog.PartNumberChgLvl FROM tblEventLog WHERE tblEventLog.EventTypeSelected = 'pn REMOVED From Wrapper'AND tblEventLog.PartNumber = tblRevRelLog_Detail.PartNumber AND tblEventLog.PartNumberChgLvl = tblRevRelLog_Detail.ChangeLevel)
```

But, note that doing two of those "inner selects" (correlated sub-queries) may significantly slow down your query.  You may be better off using a join to your "inner select".

Comment: hi Brandon, It is not that slow but still pulling the same records. I do not see any difference..

Comment: Be advised that NOT IN and NOT EXISTS are not reliably optimized by the Jet/ACE query optimizer and may not use the indexes on both sides of the comparison. IN and EXISTS by themselves will reliably use the indexes on both sides, but the NOT operator tends to cause it to fail. It may be possible to use a JOIN instead (that will always be well-optimized), particularly when editability is not required, as is the case here. The fact that you haven't had a performance issue suggests to me that your back end is actually not Jet/ACE, but some other database.

Answer (score 0):

At a guess, I'd say that your query, at the "NOT IN" point (i.e. its subquery), will effectively **not** show any partnumber if it has been removed from **any** package. This is because that subquery is searching across all packages. You will need to modify it (somehow) so that it only considers rows that pertain to the package of interest.

Look closely at that subquery. It places conditions on part numbers, change levels, and event types. But what constraints are there for packages? How is it supposed to determine what rows go with Package 1, and what rows go with Package 2?

My guess is that rows from Package 1 and Package 2 are commingled together. Since it finds a row where "EvtLog.EventTypeSelected = 'pn REMOVED From Wrapper'" is **True** for at least one of these packages, the "NOT IN" makes it **False** no matter the package you really wanted to display in your event viewer.

---

What Brandon S said above (about IN versus EXISTS), plus: You may need to use an alias; for example (making alias **EvtLog** for the sub-query):

```
"SELECT DISTINCT tblRevRelLog_Detail.PartNumber, tblRevRelLog_Detail.ChangeLevel 
FROM tblRevRelLog_Detail 
LEFT JOIN tblEventLog ON 
    (tblEventLog.PartNumber = tblRevRelLog_Detail.PartNumber) 
    AND (tblEventLog.PartNumberChgLvl = tblRevRelLog_Detail.ChangeLevel)
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT EvtLog.PartNumber, EvtLog.PartNumberChgLvl 
    FROM tblEventLog EvtLog 
    WHERE tblEventLog.PartNumber=EvtLog.PartNumber 
    AND tblEventLog.PartNumberChgLvl=EvtLog.PartNumberChgLvl
    AND EvtLog.EventTypeSelected = 'pn REMOVED From Wrapper' 
    AND EvtLog.PartNumber = tblRevRelLog_Detail.PartNumber 
    AND EvtLog.PartNumberChgLvl = tblRevRelLog_Detail.ChangeLevel) 
AND tblEventLog.TrackingNumber = """ & tempTrackingNumber & """ 
AND tblEventLog.PartNumber = tblRevRelLog_Detail.PartNumber 
AND tblEventLog.PartNumberChgLvl = tblRevRelLog_Detail.ChangeLevel"
```

Comment: Thanks for responding rskar, but still it is pulling the same records :(

Comment: I am now perplexed on what the question was. Your use of IN ( (value1, value2) NOT IN (subquery) ) isn't valid syntax in the SQL of Access 2003. You've shown your query as a Visual Basic expression - are you sure you're accessing an Access DB (and not some other DB system)? Edit your question to indicate what sort of records you want pulled.

Comment: @rskar..yes I am accessing an ACCESS DB- 2003.. and I am editing the question to show the example output records

Comment: UPdated the query..please check it out!

Comment: Re: "if I remove "a-1" from the package 1, that should no show up with that package but it should show up with package 2. With this query it is not showing up in the package 2 also." Without knowing how part numbers are made a part of or removed from a package, not sure how I could help. I can only say that there isn't any condition in your query about the package in question.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at your query a little closer.  I think your query may be more complex than it needs to be.

I think this simplified query may be what you're going after:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
   tblRevRelLog_Detail.PartNumber, 
   tblRevRelLog_Detail.ChangeLevel 
FROM tblRevRelLog_Detail 
LEFT JOIN tblEventLog ON 
   (tblEventLog.PartNumber = tblRevRelLog_Detail.PartNumber) AND 
   (tblEventLog.PartNumberChgLvl = tblRevRelLog_Detail.ChangeLevel)
WHERE
   tblEventLog.TrackingNumber = """ & tempTrackingNumber & """
   AND tblEventLog.PartNumber = tblRevRelLog_Detail.PartNumber 
   AND tblEventLog.PartNumberChgLvl = tblRevRelLog_Detail.ChangeLevel;
   AND tblEventLog.EventTypeSelected <> 'pn REMOVED From Wrapper'
```

Comment: This one does not work because , a single partnumber can have different events.. so, the record with 100 as PN with the event 'pn REMOVED From Wrapper' may not be pulled but there will be another record for the same PN with different event, so obviously that partnumber will be pulled as output, though it has an event 'pn REMOVED From Wrapper'. That is the reason for writing sub query and NOT IN condition.